# Proper functions

Tags: functional-analysis, definition

I'm a bit confused with the definition of proper function, i.e.:

"$f: X \to Y$ is proper if the inverse image of every compact set in $Y$ is compact in $X$."

Can anyone provide a more intuitive definition (even if less formal)? Some simple examples of proper and non proper functions would help a lot.

**Edit**: As additional question, is there a simple way to verify that a certain function is proper?

Comment: $\sin \colon ℂ → ℂ$ is not proper as it maps a non-compact set to a compact one. Nontrivial polynomial functions $ℂ → ℂ$ are proper because the preimage of compact set in $ℂ$ is the preimage of a bounded set which is closed in $ℂ$. As polynomial functions are continuous, these preimages are closed, and it is well known that nontrivial polynomial functions tend to infinity as their arguments grow, so a preimage of a bounded set is closed. Therefore, preimages of bounded closet sets are bounded and closed. Therefore, preimages of compact sets are compact.

Comment: So a function that maps a compact set to another compact set is automatically proper?

Comment: No, this would mean that any continuous function was proper because any continuous function maps compact sets to compact sets. To clarify my first statment, $\sin \colon ℂ → ℂ$ is not proper because $\sin^{-1}([-1..1]) \supset ℝ$ is definitely not compact.

Comment: But if $f: X \to Y$ is continuous and $X$ is compact, $f$ is proper, right? And what if $f$ is not continuous but, for instance, lower/upper-semicontinuous?

Comment: If $f \colon X → Y$ is continuous $X$ is compact and $Y$ is hausdorff, then $f$ is proper. You’d need compact sets in $Y$ to be closed in $Y$. Then their preimages would be closed in the compact space $X$ and would therefore be compact themselves. I don’t know how much you can say if you drop the assumption that $Y$ is hausdorff. I also don’t know what happens if $Y = ℝ$ and $f$ is only lower/upper-semicontinuous.